# setting the same values as for another tab

Tags: excel, date, formula

In excel tab called "A" in column A1 I would like to assign date the same as in tab "B" column A1 However when column with dates from "B" is empty it should be empty for column in tab "A" as well. But unfortunately is is filling automatically with" 00.01.1900"

Comment: What's an Excel tab? Do you mean a worksheet?

Comment: Please show us your code otherwise it is impossible to help you - maybe reading [ask], [repro] and [it's not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) will help you to improve your question.

Comment: `IF(B!A1 = 0, "", B!A1)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your B "tab" is the second sheet named "B", type this on your A Tab A1 cell.

=(B!A1="","",B!A1)

And dont forget to format A1 cell as "Short Date"

[image]